# regex not working for penetration testing to stop param which contains word script

Tags: java, regex, security, owasp, penetration-testing

I am creating a regex for controlling the attacks to my website.I am  using regex to compare the parameters that it should not contain the word 'script' in it and also should not have special character curly braces `{ and }`.

So using the java pattern matcher adding the regex I am not able to reject this param value

```
 indices.jsp--><script>alert(1)</script>
```

regex I am using

```
(?=^[\x26\x3c\x3e:a-zA-Z0-9_\s.\-\/@+* \^(),~%]+$)(?!script)|^$
```

Comment: That's a really poor approach to protecting against XSS.

Comment: Please suggest something I am using a third party  library stinger for this backed by owasp comunity.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can think of the problem the other way.
Instead of focusing on ***what you don't want***, focus ***on what you want***.

#### What are the valid values for the param?

- Find the response to this question
- Build a regex pattern that will match the valid values only.

Thus, any invalid value will be automatically rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to prevent the input of harmful parameters, you should try to make sure that their output doesn't happen in an unpredictable way.

Since you can use URL encoding and other tricks to get `<script>` to the server, you should be making sure that everywhere you're displaying data that has been input by the user, the output has been properly escaped or encoded.

Instead of the output being `<script>`, it should be `&lt;script&gt;` which will display properly to the user, but the browser won't try to execute it. If you look at this page's source, you'll see that's the way it works.

Obviously you shouldn't attempt to do this by hand. Most view technologies have a simple way of automatically performing the escape (it can even be on by default). JSTL's `c:out` does this automatically, but if you're writing raw JSP you'll need to do the `<` -> `&lt;` manually.